# bootexecute - what is autocheck for?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

What does the "autocheck" in the default data of the registry value HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\bootexecute (Data is: autocheck autochk *) do?
There's no autocheck.exe on a current (checked XP, Win7, Vista) standard Windows install, so it can't be launching an executable(?) I know what autochk does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an arbitrary name associated with the boot-time command `autochk *`.

The `BootExecute` value is a REG_MULTI_SZ, i.e., it can contain multiple separate strings.  However, if you double-click it in the Registry Editor you will notice that the default value is not three separate strings, `autocheck`, `autochk` and `*` but rather a single string `autocheck autochk *`.

Each string in `BootExecute` contains an arbitrary descriptive name followed by the command to execute.

Answer (score 1):

**Autochk** is standard Windows native application. AFAIK, is **always** present in fresh install of Windows XP.

Explain from Microsoft:

> The Autochk (Autochk.exe) utility is a version of Chkdsk. For more
>   information about Autochk, see the Windows XP Professional Resource
>   Kit. To do this, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
>    [Troubleshooting Disks and File Systems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457122.aspx)

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking about autocheck, not autochk. ;)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/embeddedwindowseefs/thread/d90a4d12-6050-4c26-9d6b-c10d3a4ca2c6). "autocheck" tells windows to run "autochk *" after previous illegal shutdown :)

> By default, its value is  "autocheck autochk *"  -  this tells Windows to run Autochk on any drive whose dirty bit is set

Answer (score 0):

Imho, this runs some internal system checks. For example, when there is a folder `C:\Program\`, windows warn about it (because it interfere with `C:\Program Files\`).

Comment: Not sure I understand. I just tried to create a C:\program folder and didn't get a warning on my XP. Is this internal warnings for the OS, not the user?

Comment: Was seen this warning (dialog box, suggesting to rename folder to `Program1`) in Windows 7. And this warning appears sometimes after booting.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't rebooted, I see what you mean now. :) This message still appears though, when you remove autocheck from the bootexecute value.

Comment: Can you check, what process shows this warning? I was lazy to do that. May be "default value" is informational for user only, and OS runs checks everytime? :)

Comment: The popup is from explorer.exe and a procmon log shows explorer first accessing C:\program and then testing if c:\program1 exists. explorer was launched by userinit.

Answer (score 0):

**Another cause example:**

In my case, Check-disk (at boot) is produced from **custom shutdown batch**/command, so the system thinks the shutdown was "Unexpected" (not normaly shutted) and sets the disk-check. If the "dirty" disk is the windows disk(C:) the disk must be unmounted first but, as the disk is in use by the system, sets an auto chkdsk at the next boot.

> *Case more explanation:*
>
> *I have set a "Run-on-idle-time" 'scheduled task' which after (1hour) pointed time expiration, triggers a custom CleanNShutDown.bat/cmd program. So, the program eg. starts the 'cleans', wait to finish and then shuts down (forced) the Computer.
> Even if I tried many shutdown switch(es) (/d) combinations (`SHUTDOWN.exe /s /t 60 /f /d p:0:0 /c "PC shutting down... (in 1 minute)"` or even with `chkntfs /x c:`) the computer keeps giving the same problem Only IF Shutting Down triggered by this program.*

How to **Check if a disk is pointed as "dirty":**

`fsutil dirty query c:`  ("c:" is disk letter)

Here is almost everything about:    ...(thanks Maximus)

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/.../force-autochk-at-every-boot-up](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d90a4d12-6050-4c26-9d6b-c10d3a4ca2c6/force-autochk-at-every-boot-up?forum=embeddedwindowseefs)